# \arrayrulewidth does not work - different thickness

Tags: tables, rules

I'm using `\arrayrulewidth` to specify my rule's width/thickness, e.g. in tables:

```
\taburulecolor{title}
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt} % Definiert die Liniendicke von Trennlinien in den array- und tabular-Umgebungen. 

%referenced by  btable
\newenvironment{mycustomtable}
{
  \begin{center}
  \def\arraystretch{1} %Seems to be better than to use %\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} % Zeilenabstand
  \tabulinesep=1.2mm % cell padding according to http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf
  \begin{longtabu}[l]
}
{
  \end{longtabu}
  %\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}% Zeilenabstand
  \end{center}
}
```

Changing `\arrayrulewidth`  does effect the thickness. But: It's not fixed and changes from time to time. In some cases, `\arrayrulewidth` seems to adjust automatically within the same environment, e.g. after a pagebreak. Why is that and how can I specify arrayrulewidth to a fixed value that will not (never) change?

Comment: Please post a MWE ;-)

Comment: Your example code doesn't seem to be an example of anything? It shows arrayrulewidth being set twice but it is not used anywhere. Please edit it to be a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` in a form that shows two different rule widths. Then we will be able to say why they are different.

Answer (score 4):

Since not all packages are given, I can only guess about packages.

It is a better method to change `\arrayrulewidth` within a group such that it does not interfere with other tables environments. Fortunately you are using a `\newenvironment` already, so it is quite comfortable to place it there. For better handling, it would be better to provide an (optional) argument to the `mycustomtable` such that the array rule width can be adapted without changing the code, but that is up to the OP...

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabu}%
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\taburulecolor{title}
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt} % Definiert die Liniendicke von Trennlinien in den array- und tabular-Umgebungen. 

%referenced by  btable
\newenvironment{mycustomtable}
{
  % Lets overexaggerate a little bit ;-)
  \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{5pt} 

  \begin{center}
  \def\arraystretch{1} %Seems to be better than to use %\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} % Zeilenabstand
  \tabulinesep=1.2mm % cell padding according to http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf

  \begin{longtabu}[l]
}
{
  \end{longtabu}
  %\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}% Zeilenabstand
  \end{center}
}

\begin{mycustomtable}{llll}
\hline
This & is & a & table \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{mycustomtable}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
This & is & a & table \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In order to compare with a standard table, I have added a `tabular` environment too.

[image]