# How to achieve this 'regional two-column' effect (specific case)?

Tags: two-column, alignment, comparison

I'm making a comparison in my essay and met a difficulty which I have trouble in typesetting. The deisred effect is like below (the red lines are auxilary and are not displayed in the final result). I'd appreciate a solution that uses as few extra settings & environments as possible since they may clash with incumbent settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to add all the details I see from your image, including the spacing between the left column and the dotted line.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\newcommand\compitem{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny \textbullet}}$}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.1\textwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}}
      A & vs. & B \\ 
      &&
    \end{tabular}
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\centering}p{0.5cm}p{0.3\textwidth}@{\hspace{2em}}:>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.5cm}p{0.3\textwidth}@{\hspace{2em}}}
        \compitem & Difference 1 & \compitem & Difference 1' \\
        \compitem & Difference 2: lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum & \compitem & Difference 2': lorem ipsum \\
        \compitem & Difference 3: lorem ipsum & \compitem & Difference 3': lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{table}

Lorem ipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: Output from the code]

I have used answers related to
[dotted line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122301/how-to-add-vertical-and-horizontal-dashed-lines-in-array-and-tabular-enviroments),
[fixed width columns](https://texblog.org/2019/06/03/control-the-width-of-table-columns-tabular-in-latex/),
[centered bullet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8534/283484),
[line thickness](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/191547/283484),
[adding column space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/283484)